# String replace in ubuntu python not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, fabric

```
def monkey_patch_string(file_name, old_string, new_string):
    # Read in the file
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f :
        filedata = f.read()

    # Replace the target string
    filedata = filedata.replace(old_string, new_string)

    # Write the file out again
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(filedata)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_name   =   sys.argv[1]
    old_string  =   sys.argv[2]
    new_string  =   sys.argv[3]
    monkey_patch_string(file_name, old_string, new_string)
```

I have this file which i use as a process to replace strings during deployment. Its execution is done remotely via fabric script.

```
old_string  =   '"{}"'.format('$CONFIG_DIR')
new_string  =   '"{}"'.format('$CONFIG_DIR --logfile /var/www/' + domain_name + '/logs/transmission.log')
run('python deployment/monkey_patch.py /etc/default/transmission-daemon '+ old_string + ' ' + new_string)
```

But rather than replacing the old string to the new string it replaces the entire file with some garbage values of new string.
I even copied the file to my windows env and repeated exact same steps and it works but on ubuntu.
All the while i am root user and anyway its writing something to the file, so its not permission issue as well.

I have tried this file for some other string and file and it works.

```
old_string  =   'debian-transmission'
new_string  =   'www-data'
run('python deployment/monkey_patch.py /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon '+ old_string + ' ' + new_string)
```

I suspect its something to do with the dollar sign and fabric module but i cant figure out exactly. Anyone has clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Its the way fabric execute commands 
e.g. `/bin/bash -l -c "Your commands goes here"`

Quoting the string within the command space was creating the issue. Essentially its the string quoting issue.
Solved it using pipes.

```
import pipes
old_string  =   pipes.quote('$CONFIG_DIR')
new_string  =   pipes.quote('$CONFIG_DIR --logfile /var/www/' + domain_name + '/logs/transmission.log')
```